# YouTube video embed to the site

Tags: wordpress, embed

I embed a Youtube video to my website when I inspect elements I get the following error. anyone can help ?? and also I get an error for google Maps, also I get the following error.
Thanks in advance
https://apmtanzania.com/testapm/telecom/
This is the page.

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at o (chrome-extension://lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk/content/tbvws-bulk-script.js:1:5115)
at Object.374 (chrome-extension://lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk/content/tbvws-bulk-script.js:1:5262)
at t (chrome-extension://lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk/content/tbvws-bulk-script.js:1:110)
at Object.373 (chrome-extension://lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk/content/tbvws-bulk-script.js:1:4560)
at t (chrome-extension://lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk/content/tbvws-bulk-script.js:1:110)
at chrome-extension://lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk/content/tbvws-bulk-script.js:1:451
at chrome-extension://lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk/content/tbvws-bulk-script.js:1:462

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Turn off some browser extensions. I don't have these errors in my console. Only Google Maps Key error.